# Mocha.run() exits without awaiting async tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I want to use `mocha` to run some basic post-deploy tests against live services. I want to programmatically load tests based upon a config object passed to the test script.

The problem I'm encountering is that `mocha.run()` executes and exits the `node` process without continuing with the rest of the code. It is not clear to me how to force `node` to wait for the `mocha` result and continue with the rest of the code.

**mocha-setup.js**

```
const Mocha = require('mocha');
const util = require('util');

const { Test, Suite } = Mocha;

const timeoutMillis = 300000; // five minutes

const mocha = new Mocha({
  timeout: timeoutMillis,
  reporter: 'mochawesome',
  reporterOptions: {
    reportDir: '../reports/unit'
  },
  color: true,
});

const makeSuite = (suiteName) => Suite.create(mocha.suite, suiteName);

const runMochaTests = async (tests, config) => {
  const suite = makeSuite('My programmatic test suite');
  tests.forEach(({ test, statement }) => {
    suite.addTest(new Test(statement, async () => {
      await test(config);
    }));
  });

  console.log('This logs as expected.');

  const promisifyMocha = util.promisify(() => mocha.run());
  const result = await promisifyMocha(); // code seems to exit here

  console.log('I am never logged');
  console.log(result); // also never logged

  // `result` is never returned, and higher level code implementing `runMochaTests` does not continue either
  return result; // Eventually, I want to return the number of failures
};

module.exports = {
  runMochaTests,
};
```

The plan is for `runMochaTests` to return the number of failures. `runMochaTests()` will be used by different higher order code modules as necessary.

Lastly, in my best life, I would not have to manually promisify mocha at all. If there was a way to use something like `const result = await mocha.run()`, that feels like the best implementation.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that `Mocha` is fundamentally about event listeners, not promises. Using [this reference code](https://github.com/corybill/lambda-mocha-runner/blob/master/lib/proxies/mocha-proxy.js), I ended up with...

```
const runMochaTests = async (tests, config) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const testResults = [];
  let numberOfFailures = 0;
  try {
    const suite = makeSuite('Verify Regional Apps');
    tests.forEach(({ test, statement }) => {
      suite.addTest(new Test(statement, async () => {
        await test(config);
      }));
    });

    const runner = mocha.run();

    runner.on('test end', (testResult) => {
      if (testResult.state === 'failed') numberOfFailures += 1;
      testResults.push(testResult);
    });

    runner.on('end', () => {
      runner.removeAllListeners('test end');
      runner.removeAllListeners('end');

      ClearModule.all(); // Needed to ensure all tests are executed every execution.

      resolve(numberOfFailures);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    reject(err);
  }
});
```